# Getting Eclipse CDT Helios to recognize i586 gcc mingw32 as a compiler, any ideas?

Tags: eclipse, mingw32, eclipse-cdt, compilation-target

I installed CDT direct by extracting the tar.  It detects the other compilers, but fails to recognize mingw32 as a compilation target.  Any ideas?  Unless you've tried a tutorial and it recognizes properly, please no links to the first 5 google results...I tried them.

By the way, I'm on 10.04 LTS.  The same situation occurs on 11.04 and 11.10.

Comment: my hackish fix at the moment is to have a shellscript rename gcc to gcc-native and the mingw binary to gcc.  this is a stop-gap hack NOT a solution.  if somebody has a real fix, I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: If anyone comes up with a better solution, let me know and I'll change the accepted answer to yours

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While [this](http://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Eclipse,_CDT_%26_MingW_Setup_Guide) guide targets wxwidgets, it's the best answer I could find.  Also, it targets windows, but the theory remains the same.